# Can you help reconcile the difference in answer from this Poisson probability question?

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

Probability of salesperson making a sale off one person is $3\%$. If 100 people are contacted (and the distribution of sales is Poisson), what is the probability of making at least one sale?

I used $P(X\ge1)=1-P(X=0)=1-e^{-3}=0.95021$ with $n=100, p=0.03$ hence $\lambda=3$

The book gave $0.9524$. What did I do wrong?

Comment: The book's result can be obtained with the expression (using Binomial distribution)
$$
1-P(X=0) = 1- 0.97^{100} \approx 0.952~447
$$
So I think it's just a matter of choise, which calculation method one uses.

Comment: Do you think one is more reasonable than the other? This was a Poisson end of chapter question so I was only thinking about Poisson (and of course this is the classic trap where I won't learn how to pick the proper method if I only stay in one chapter)

Comment: Also please post as answer so I can vote it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The book's answer apparently uses a more straightforward method, assuming the Binomial distribution. That's because with a binomial distribution, the answer is
$$
1- P(X=0) = 1- 0.97^{100} \approx 0.952~447
$$
This is a simpler approach, not using the Poisson approximation. The Poisson approximation is easier to calculate but it applies only to "large $n$". In this case $n=100$ which is not too large. In a way, I would say that the book's answer is closer to the "real world" answer, but on the other hand, if the book is trying to **teach** the Poisson approximation, your solution with
$$
1- P(X=0) \approx 1- e^{-3}
$$
would be the correct way to calculate it **with the Poisson approximation**.